# Summation problem in an expected value question

Tags: probability

A fair die is successfully rolled. Let X and Y denote, respectively, the number of rolls necessary to obtain a 6 and a 5. Find E(X|Y=5).

My attempt is:

E(X|Y=5) = 1*P(X=1|Y=5) + 2*P(X=2|Y=5) + 3*P(X=3|Y=5) + ... + 6*P(X=6|Y=5) + ...
         = 1/5 + 2*(4/5)*(1/5) + 3*(4/5)^2*(1/5) + 4*(4/5)^3*(1/5) + 0 + 6*(4/5)^4*(1/6) + ...

I'm stuck at evaluating the sum of the terms from 6*P(X=6|Y=5) onwards.

Comment: What does 'successfully rolled' mean?

Comment: Also, does '6 and 5' mean exactly one 5 and exactly one 6?

Comment: Successfully rolled means there'll definitely be a value for the roll, and yea, it's like a geometric distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $Y=n+1$. Then rolls from $1$ to $n$ can produce anything but 5, roll $n+1$ produces 5, and every roll from $n+2$ can produce anything. Hence 6 appears in each roll from $1$ to $n$ with probability $a=1/5$, in roll 
$n+1$ with probability $0$ and in each roll starting from roll $n+2$ with probability $b=1/6$.
Thus, $P[X\geqslant k\mid Y=n+1]=(1-a)^{k-1}$ for every $1\leqslant k\leqslant n+1$, and $P[X\geqslant k]=(1-a)^n(1-b)^{k-n-2}$ for every $k\geqslant n+2$. Using the identity
$$
E[Z]=\sum_{k\geqslant1}P[Z\geqslant k],
$$
this shows that
$$
E[X\mid Y=n+1]=\sum_{i=0}^n(1-a)^i+(1-a)^n\sum_{i\geqslant0}(1-b)^i,
$$
that is,
$$
E[X\mid Y=n+1]=\frac1a(1-(1-a)^{n+1})+(1-a)^n\frac1b=5+2\cdot\left(\tfrac45\right)^n.
$$
Finally, plug in $n=4$ to get $E[X\mid Y=5]=5+2\cdot\left(\tfrac45\right)^4$.

*Sanity checks:* If $n=0$, the result is $7$ (why?), and if $n\to\infty$, the result converges to $5$ (why?).

Answer (score 0):

OK, so if I got the question right and you need exactly one 5 and exactly one 6, then what you need is $S_1$: toss 5 and $S_2$: toss 6 and it does not matter in what order this happens. Then what you need is toss $\mathit{anything}$ other than either 5 or 6 in the first $k$ tosses, then either $S_1$ or $S_2$, then anything except either 5 or 6 in the next $r$ tosses, and then either $S_1$ or $S_2$. So you have two successes in $k+r+2$ tosses and the probability of this event is 
$$
P(S)= 2 \cdot\bigg(\frac{4}{6} \bigg)^{k+r} \cdot \frac{1}{6^2}
$$

Comment: Not sure if you've gotten the question right. I believe the question wants us to find the expected value of the number of rolls needed to obtain the 1st 6 given that the 1st 5 is obtained on the fifth roll.

Comment: I don't see how this information affects the outcome other than 5th toss wasn't 6. In any case, expectation of Geometric RV is $\frac{1}{P_S}$